# can I use BIRT without Eclipse?

Tags: birt, business-intelligence

I'd like to use BIRT as stand-alone application (without Eclipse).

How is it possible? 
Could I run BIRT as web service?

Does BIRT have web interface?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIRT and Eclipse can not be seperated, kind of like playing Wii without a Television is not possible.

But your user interface can be a web page. Apache is often choosen as delivery tool.

You can download open source BIRT from http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

If you have any issues getting set up, pretty much every solution can be found by Google.

Comment: I don't think BIRT is shareware.

Comment: You are correct poor word choice on my part. 'shareware' > 'open source'